# how to pass array values to dojo pie chart using javascript

Tags: dojo

Please can any one help me out how to pass array values to the dojo pie chart using javascript..

I need to update the pie chart on fly. on selection on user from gridivew..

Comment: You have both grid and charts in your questions --- both are big topics. The more different things you mention in your question, the less number of people will try to answer. Try bite-size simple questions instead of complex ones.

Answer (score 2):

I can help with Pie chart:

```
my_chart.
  // let's update data
  updateSeries("your series name here", your_data_here).
  // finished updating, now let's show the changes
  render();
```

Adding a series with the same name will work too:

```
my_chart.
  // let's update data
  addSeries("your series name here", your_data_here).
  // finished updating, now let's show the changes
  render();
```

Comment: how to do the click event.. where I need to call this UpdateSeries funcation on div tag? or need to keep button there?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on how you update series. If you do it on click, attach it to whatever is a source of clicks. It can be button, or anything else. The comments do not allow formatted examples, but you can do it like that: dojo.connect(node, "onclick", updateSeries); or: dojo.connect(dojo.byId("myNodeId"), "onclick", updateSeries);